# Encoding problems with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I get small boxes instead of swedish character å, ä and ö, despite that I'm using UTF-8 everywhere I can think of! I saved the files with UTF-8 without BOM from notepad and the HTML page has meta charset="utf-8" and I changed the table in the database to UTF8_swedish_ci. What have I missed? Preciate some help! Thanks!

EDIT:
Would it be better to use latin and save all files in latin instead of UTF8? But could I still use the meta charset="utf-8" in the HTML head?

Comment: do you see the data correctly in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes is't OK in phpMyAdmin. Correctly? Could you explain?

Comment: are you doing `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8")` before doing other queries?

Comment: Yes! I do a lot of things but nothing works! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what collation you using in MySQL connection? Set right one.

you can change collation for current connection using query:
`set names utf8 collate utf8_swedish_ci")`

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used PHP for some time, should I add the code above like a query to the table?

Comment: @3D-kreativ, yes you execute that command on the same connection as your query (just as you would a query), and before the query.

Comment: be sure that in database your data storred correctly. If you insert wrong encoded data, you should export end reimport it.

Comment: Now it's working! First I didn't write the query correct, but then with "SET NAMES 'utf8'" it got better! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are issues in PHP.
I was in your situation: database in UTF8, HTML page in UTF8, but the data that i got through **mysql_fetch_assoc()** was not well encoded (ergo, displaying ? chars like your case).

My solution was to use **utf8_encode()** and **utf8_decode()** in my php source to handle the input and output of the database.

See if this solution works for you.

PS. the collation is not the char encoding. Google what collation is.
From what I know (not much) is defaulted to swedish_ci because swedish is the most complete in characters. Correct this if I'm wrong.